# Data Grid View and Vertical scrollbars issue

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, datagridview, scroll

I realized something annoying when using a data grid view control. When I try to set the cell's height by setting the RowTemplate height property to fit more records on the grid, the vertical scroll bar stops acting nicely and the grid doesnt display all the records (it only shows the records that fit on the available space plus one extra record!) until you resize the columns or something like that! But if I set the AutoSizeRowsMod property to AllCells the grid displays all the records, however the cell's height is now too big for me! 
Is there a way to control the cell's height and still show all the records on the DGV? Does it even make sense that it's behaving this way?

Thanks